# Angular 2 gauge control

Tags: angular

currently I am using primeng with angular 2 and I am really satisfied with their components. 
Unfortunately there is no gauge control. Is there something that I could use that is open source? 
I already checked vaadin and wijmo5,  but both are not free. 
I cannot change the complete framework or buy a whole one only for one component.

Answer (score 4):

Would this do? Gauge graph

Live demo:
https://subarroca.github.io/ng-gauge/

Github project: 
https://github.com/subarroca/ng-gauge

example:

```
<ng2-kw-gauge [radius]="20" ></ng2-kw-gauge>
```

set propeties on the ng2-kw-guage as per the github link's option section.

For example, I set the radius.

Comment: But the documentation is not really clear.  Do you have example code?

Comment: updated my answer: check the github project link and you'll see the options for manipulation at the bottom.

Comment: I will try it tomorrow

Comment: Tried it so many times but cannot get it  run.  I am using the system.config.js but it won't run.  Any examples for using it in that way?